# Flutter ListView.builder creating an extra height

Tags: flutter, dart, listview

I have a `ListView` inside a `DefaultControllerTab`, and for some reason it's creating an extra spacing above it, please check the image.

[image]

### Scaffold

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(album.name ?? ''),
        backgroundColor: context.primary.withOpacity(0.6),
      ),
      body: const Stack(
        children: [
          AlbumHeader(),
          Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(child: SizedBox.expand()),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: AlbumContentView(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
      floatingActionButton: const RatingFloatingActionButton(),
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
    );
```

### White container

The widget `AlbumContentView` is the white space with rounded corners, this:

```
return DecoratedBox(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(32),
          topRight: Radius.circular(32),
        ),
        color: context.background,
      ),
      child: const Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: [
            AlbumRating(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            AlbumGenreList(),
            SizedBox(
              height: 16,
            ),
            Expanded(child: AlbumTabView()),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ).animate().fadeIn();
```

### Tabs

```
return DefaultTabController(
      length: 3,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TabBar(
            indicatorColor: context.primary,
            labelColor: context.primary,
            unselectedLabelColor: context.onSurface.withOpacity(0.6),
            tabs: AlbumTabs.values
                .map(
                  (e) => Tab(
                    icon: Icon(e.icon),
                    text: e.label,
                  ),
                )
                .toList(),
          ),
          const SizedBox(
            height: 16,
          ),
          const Expanded(
            child: Material(
              child: TabBarView(
                children: [
                  AlbumAboutTabContent(),
                  AlbumTracksTabContent(),
                  Icon(Icons.directions_bike),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
```

### List View widget

```
return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: tracks.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 8),
        child: InkWell(
          onTap: () {},
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
          child: Ink(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
              border: Border.all(color: context.onSurface.withOpacity(0.2)),
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Text(tracks[index].name!),
                  const Icon(Icons.arrow_outward),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

I have no idea what is that extra white space, sinalized with " ? ? ? "
Thanks

Comment: The `ListView.builder` has a named parameter of padding with default top/bottom padding around the widget. Give `padding: EdgeInsets.zero` inside the listview.buider below the `itemCount`.

Comment: I think we need to see the code that actually adds the tabs and list. I believe it's `AlbumContentView`. I suspect you wrapped both in an extended and the space is then actually space below the tabs and not space above the list. In that case simply don't wrap the tabs in an Expanded because it forces it to take more space than necessary

Comment: @SalmanAhmed You were right! Do you have idea where that padding might be coming from?

Comment: That's default padding of the widget `ListviewBuilder`.

Comment: You can also wrap your widget in `MediaQuery.removePadding` if it is still persisting the blank space.

Comment: @SalmanAhmed Just putting EdgeInsets.zero solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Top padding is set to 20.0 by default for ListView. If you add zero padding inside Listview, your problem will gone. `padding: EdgeInsets.zero`